# Using Preact in Lightning Web Component

Tags: web-component, preact, lwc

Recently installed the project noted here: https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2020/11/how-to-use-apex-natively-with-svelte-vue-and-preact-within-lwc.html to test a theory on using Preact in a Lightning Web Component. Observed that in the Preact component any click in the component fires the onclick function for the first element rendered in the component (with an onclick property), any additional clicks or clicking directly on other elements (with or without an onclick properties) only fire the function for the first element. This behavior tracks with a separate project I've been working on that includes Preact. Does anyone know what would cause this and/or have suggestions on ways to address?

I'm assuming this is related to the LWC wrapper and how it redirects browser events to be processed, but I'm out of my depth in terms of fully debugging that path.

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing and having a hard time to get around this.

Answer (score 0):

I ran this by the author of the linked blog post and we confirmed this doesn't work in an actual org, though it works fine in a local dev sandbox. Likely culprit is locker service, but neither the author nor I was willing to try to verify that, and there wouldn't be a whole lot to be done about it even if it were confirmed.

Short answer, Preact doesn't work in LWC framework currently.